# PlaySound() function does not play sound on Visual Studio Release Mode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, c++20

I've been experimenting with the `PlaySound()` function in Visual C++, but it appears that when I close and re-open a project, `PlaySound()` doesn't make any sound whatsoever (in Release Mode).
The function returns `FALSE`
However, running the code in sync still takes time.

However, when I change the mode to Debug, the sound plays completely fine.

My project settings are set to default, except for "C/C++ Code Generation" is set to "Multi-Threaded (No DLL dependency)" for both Debug and Release.

Is there any reason as to why this happens, and how can I fix this?

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
//winmm.lib is linked

int main()
{
    PlaySound(TEXT("SystemHand"), NULL, SND_SYNC); //no sound on RELEASE mode, but works on DEBUG
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v=vs.85)) you should be using the `SND_ALIAS` flag. You should be checking the return value too.

Comment: Your code works for me in 32 and 64 bit Debug and Release with and without SND_ALIAS. *shrug*

Comment: I found if you change System SoundScheme to "no sound", PlaySound will always return false (0);
To open SoundSchema: win + r > run mmsys.cpl > sounds tab > sound schema.

Comment: `Debug` or `Release` mode should make no difference in playing the sound. You have a comment `//winmm.lib is linked` - is the same lib linked in both configurations? Could you instead try `#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")` ?